# PHP strcmp is not returning the correct answer with session variable

Tags: php, session, strcmp, gettype

I have a session variable $_SESSION['condition'], I know it is set because when I entered this:

```
echo $_SESSION['condition']." = "."Below Average";
```

It returns:

```
Below Average = Below Average
```

When I do a gettype() on the session variable it returns type "string".

Yet when I do strcmp() it returns: -34

I have also tried an IF statement with == rather than strcmp testing for equality AND an IF statement casting them both as strings and testing if they are equal with no luck.

Any reason why this could be?

Comment: How are you setting the value of $_SESSION['condition']? Is it possible there is a stray newline character in there that would be invisible?

Comment: What does `var_dump($_SESSION['condition']);` output?

Comment: Can you show us your IF statement you are using?

Comment: Look at the return values of strcmp() as well Eric. It doens't return TRUE if that is what you are hoping for. In fact, it returns 0 if the strings match which is wrongly evaluated to false. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be a whitespace or invisible character that is causing this problem with strcmp(). You can use trim() to help clean up strings and then use a literal equation operator, === to test for true equality. See below

```
$condition = trim($_SESSION['condition']);

if ($condition === 'Below Average') {
    echo 'True';
} else {
    echo 'Nope!';
}
```

See if that helps at all.

Also, you can use var_dump($_SESSION['condition']); to inspect the value.

Comment: You're probably right that it's whitespace. `strcmp(' ', 'B')` returns `-34`.

Comment: No dice, I get a "Nope!"

Comment: Wait! $condition = trim($_SESSION['condition']); worked but $string = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $string);  didn't, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[`strcmp()`](http://php.net/strcmp) function (usually) returns the difference of the first different character between the strings.

So, if there's a difference between your strings anywhere, `strcmp()` stops there and returns the difference between the ASCII values of the two characters.

As Barmar pointed out in the comments, the difference between a space and B is -34 and I believe this is the case.

This can be confirmed by:

```
$v1 = ord(' ') - ord('B');
$v2 = strcmp('B', ' ');

if($v1 == $v2) {
    echo 'True';
}
```

Output:

```
True
```

[**Demo!**](http://3v4l.org/jf1TF)

To make sure this doesn't happen, you can either use `trim()` as Rottingham suggested, or a regular expression to strip out all the unwanted characters.

For replacing all the whitespace:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $string);
```

To remove the whitespace from beginning and end:

```
$string = trim($string);
```

Hope this helps!